# Number of increasing subsequences variant

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greatest-common-divisor

Given an array we need to find out the number of coprime increasing subsequences.coprime increasing subquence is a increasing subsequence where gcd of all the elements in the subsequence is 1.
I dont know how to solve this.Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't answer this question.This is from a live hiring challenge over hackereath.